# not able to see result after running db query to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I want to get results after running SQL query to MySQL with node, but unfortunately I have the following problem, my codes are as follows:

```
socket.on("userpass", function (data) {

        var res = data.split(",");

     //  console.log(data);
      console.log(res[1]);
      var username =  res[0];
      var password =  res[1];

         connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', username + 'AND password = ?',password, function (err, result, fields) {

            console.log("eror     ",err);
            console.log("result   ",result);
            console.log(fields+"  fields   ");
```

My problem is as follows :

```
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\chat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Add a space between `?` and `AND`: `username = ?', username + ' AND password`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have write like this,

```
socket.on("userpass", function (data) {

    var res = data.split(",");

    //  console.log(data);
    console.log(res[1]);
    var username = res[0];
    var password = res[1];

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function (err, result, fields) {

        console.log("eror     ", err);
        console.log("result   ", result);
        console.log(fields + "  fields   ");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '${username}' AND password='${password}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
})
```